# Import 32-bit dsn into 64-bit window server

Tags: windows, 64-bit, odbc, 32-bit

We are in process of upgrading from 32-bit windows 2003 server to 64-bit windows 2003 server. We have hundreds of ODBC DSN's created on the 32-bit, which we now want to work on the 64-bit box. Using the registry export and importing into the 64-bit box results in those entries ending up on the 32-bit part of the odbc windows registry tree on the 64-bit box. Is there a way to import these DSNs into the 64-bit registry tree of ODBC?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you have to use the 64 BIT version of REG.EXE or REGEDIT.EXE (in %SystemRoot%\System32) to import in the 64 BIT Section.  For the 32 BIT Section of the Registry, use the 32 BIT version of REG.EXE or REGEDIT.EXE (in %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64) to import in the 32 BIT Section.